# Got error when trying to specific Canned ACL

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, boto

I am trying to use boto api to upload photos to Amazon S3.  I can successfully upload photos there if I haven't specified the Canned ACL.

But if I specified ACL as follow.  I got the following error.

```
mp = self._bucket.initiate_multipart_upload(name)
pool = Pool(processes=self.NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSES)
pool.apply_async(mp.upload_part_from_file(fp=buffer, part_num=counter, headers=headers, policy='public-read'))
```

Error as follow.

```
<Error><Code>InvalidArgument</Code><Message>The specified header is not valid in this context</Message><ArgumentValue>public-read</ArgumentValue><ArgumentName>x-amz-acl</ArgumentName><RequestId>xxx</RequestId><HostId>xxx</HostId></Error>
```

I tried for a long time but still cannot get any hints.  Anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `upload_part_from_file` method should not have a policy parameter.  This is a bug in boto.  To assign a policy to a multipart file, you specify the canned policy as the `policy` parameter on the `initiate_multipart_upload` call and then upload the parts and complete the upload.  Don't try to pass the policy when uploading the individual parts.  We should create an issue on github for boto to remove the policy parameter.  It's confusing and doesn't work.

Comment: Yup.  This is very confusing.  And I found that not much documentation is available for boto too.